# Programmatically post and tag media on Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I searched into the Instagram API docs and I discovered that posting images and tagging products through API requests is not (yet?) possible.

Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Depends from type of account that you use:

- **Personal account**. Not possible to post via API
- **Business account**. Posible via API Graph for Instagram. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview

Comment: Thanks, but I see this: "The Content Publishing API is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners only. We are not accepting new applicants at this time.". In that page, btw, I see no "products-tagging" feature.